# Implementing Multiclass Dice Loss Function

Tags: neural-networks, python, tensorflow, keras

I am doing multi class segmentation using UNet. My output from the model is,

```
outputs = layers.Conv3D(n_classes, (1, 1, 1), padding="same", activation='softmax')(d4)
```

Using SparseCategoricalCrossentropy I can train the network fine. Now I would like to also try dice coefficient as the loss function. My true and pred shapes are as follows,

```
y_true = tf.constant([0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
y_pred = tf.constant([[0.9, 0.95, 0.90], [0.1, 0.8, 0.5], [0.1, 0.8, 0.9]])
```

I've implemented dice coeffient as follows,

```
def softargmax(x, beta=1e10):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    x_range = tf.range(x.shape.as_list()[-1], dtype=x.dtype)
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax(x*beta) * x_range, axis=-1)

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-7):
    y_true = K.flatten(K.one_hot(K.cast(y_true, 'int32'), num_classes=n_classes))

    y_pred = softargmax(y_pred)
    y_pred = K.flatten(K.one_hot(K.cast(y_pred, 'int32'), num_classes=n_classes))

    intersect = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=-1)
    denom = K.sum(y_true + y_pred, axis=-1)
    return K.mean((2. * intersect / (denom + smooth)))

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

I can test this in isolation

```
dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

However when I try to use this as the loss function I get an error that says,

```
 ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

Googling for the error I found that this happens when a function is not differentiable. while debugging problem seems to be arise from `y_pred = K.flatten...` line but it works for `y_true` why does it fail for `y_pred`?